# Understand html5 tag and css3 style

Tags: html, css

Hay every one I need some help to understand html5 and css3.

Here I have some code thats is written in html5. Both article will be on the same page but they will have diffrent layout and they need to keep the article tag. So my quesiten is how can I use the article tags on both and still use diffrent layout.

```
Layout 1
<article>
   <header>
      <hgroup>
         <h1>Welcome to the article site </h1>
         <h2>This is new Article</h2>
      </hgroup>
      <p>This article is all about new movies</p>
   </header>
  <footer><p>Written by some one</p></footer>
</article> 

Layout 2
<article>
   <header>
      <hgroup>
         <h1>Welcome to the article site </h1>
         <h2>This is new Article</h2>
      </hgroup>
      <p>This article is all about new food</p>
   </header>
  <footer><p>Written by some one</p></footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an attribute to one or both of the `article` elements.

For example, `class`:

```
<article class="layout-1">
</article>

<article class="layout-2">
</article>
```

(Choose a `class` value that describes the difference between these articles, if possible.)

In the CSS, you can style them by using the class selector:

```css
.layout-1 {}
.layout-2 {}
```

---

Note that the `hgroup` element is obsolete ([non-conforming](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)).

Comment: Thanks I will look in to it when I am at home

Comment: +1. Suggestion: Using "movies" and "food" for the class names would make this answer clearer.

Comment: @Alohci: I figured not to give an explicit example, as I don’t know if the topic (food/movies) is the deciding factor here. Maybe there are many more of those categories, but the layout difference is because of rating/featured state/author etc. I wouldn’t advise to use those category names as `class` value in this case.

Comment: Fair enough. I can understand that.